# what this kind of syntax mean in react "dispatch: Dispatch<CartAction>"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have a code which has function like this

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<CartAction>) => ({
  onAddProduct: (
      key: string,
      product: ProductData,
      productCurrency: string,
  ) => void dispatch(
     addToCart(key, product, productCurrency),
    ),
});
```

**I could not understand `Dispatch<CartAction>` what it is ?**

Comment: This is react/redux written in [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/), check this also https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are writing `(dispatch: Dispatch<CartAction>)` this means you are passing a parameter named as `dispatch` and it would be of `Dispatch` class object having type `CardAction`. Dispatch accepts generic parameters so we need to pass it a type, which is `CardAction` in this scenario.

Comment: Yes. Types are defined in Typescript.